# The volume in cubic meters of water in an aquarium is given by the polynomial $V(x)=x^3-16x^2+79x-120$

Tags: calculus

The volume in cubic meters of water in an aquarium is given by the polynomial $$V(x)=x^3-16x^2+79x-120$$

If the depth in feet can be represented by *y*, what are the possible 
dimensions of the rectangular aquarium in terms of x ?.

I don't understand what to do I started by solving for the zeros? is that $x=3,5,8$ ?

Comment: "...can be represented by, what..." . Common, don't tease us: by **what** ?!

Comment: For a start, we can have a negative volume, right? So there are intervals for x that don't work...And since the factors are (x-3) , (x-5) , (x-8), how does that relate to the formula to the volume???

Comment: Dear user...I put a "blank" in the post where it seems you left out some information. If you could please replace the blank with the missing information, we can help...